# Get svn commits by date range using node-svn-ultimate library

Tags: node.js

I installed the node-svn-ultimate library on my node.js project to get information about commits in a repository.

I can get the commits using the revision parameter

`const revisions = { "revision":lastRevision - quantity + ':' + lastRevision, 'HEAD':lastRevision }`

Looking at the Github https://github.com/peteward44/node-svn-ultimate
I did not really understand how to do the same but using a date range.

On my console, I can get it done using

`` svn /repository/trunk`-r {2019-08-29}:{2019-08-30} ``

Using the library I have tried some possibilities like:

```
  const range = {"range": '2019-08-29'+':'+'2019-09-02'}
  const range = {"range": '{2019-08-29}'+':'+'{2019-09-02}'}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
{ RangeError [ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER]: stdout maxBuffer length exceeded
    at Socket.onChildStdout (child_process.js:348:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:13)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  cmd:
   'svn log /repository/Trunk --xml --non-interactive ' }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error on the command was actually the property "range".
There is no property range, I have to use "revision" instead and it works when I call it:

```
const range = {"revision": '{2019-08-29}'+':'+'{2019-09-02}'}
```